# How can I check the status of 100 sites in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of 100 sites  and I need to see if they are available or not. If they are available I need to check the response body for certain content, I also need to check the MX records.

I can do this pretty easily synchronously but it’s takes a long time.

I can’t work out how I would approach this with promises. I’m sure I’m missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your help.

All the tutorials I look at run for 1 url not 100s

Comment: you looking for `Promise.allSettled` with `os.cpus().length` as your chunk size?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Node by executing async functions within an async loop. Any HTTP requests made in the async function won't wait for responses before proceeding.

Of course, you'll still need to solve for all the CORS access and such.

Here's a simplified example:

```
const urls = [
    "https://www.typescriptlang.org/",
    "https://www.w3.org/",
    "https://developer.mozilla.org/",
];

async function checkWebsite(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const status = await response.status;
    return status
}

urls.forEach(async url => {
    const statusCode = await checkWebsite(url);
    console.log(statusCode)
});
```

Comment: Not sure `async` in a `forEach` is a thing. You probably mean `Promise.all`, or the venerable [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

Comment: @tadman - Not sure that `Promise.map` is a thing. The link you posted is for a third party library. It's not a native JS method.  Promise methods may be more appropriate if you're going to try to sequence things after the function executes, but `async forEach` is referenced in the `array.forEach` MDN examples. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: That's why I linked it instead of just mentioning it. The MDN docs explicitly state that async `forEach` "does not wait for promises" which can be a huge problem, especially if this process terminates before any of them are resolved. It'll appear to do nothing.

Comment: @tadman It depends on the use-case and your implementation. It maybe the right tool for the job if you don't want or need the added complexity of a thenable promise.

Comment: @tadman -- I looked over the library you posted. The fundamental problem that I have with stuff like this is that it's essentially a convenience library that acts as a runtime.  It ends up making things easier for you as a developer in the short-term, and your customers pay a penalty of unnecessary filesize and execution time on every page load until forever. It also incurs technical debt of making sure that latest versions are being used, etc.

Comment: It is intended as a server-side thing where the cost is marginal.

Comment: @tadman I would not have used Bluebird `Promise.map`, it's basically [deprecated](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/#%EF%B8%8Fnote%EF%B8%8F). I would instead go fo `[].map` and `Promise.all`. And i don't thing there is an issue of using async in forEach. it can be a foot gun. but as Josh said. it depends on the use-case... map will also allocate a new Array which isn't always needed. I would however like to point out that if you are only intrested in status code then it might be worth just to do a `HEAD` request

Comment: Another good way to go might be Promise.allSettled() -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Answer (score -1):

If its NodeJS and not Javascript, you could use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and push the results to an array, like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const websites = [/* Array of website URL's go here */];
var statuses = [];
for (let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
  asynchronousProcess(function(){
    var response = await axios.get(websites[i]);
    var status = await response.status;
    statuses.push(status)
  });
}
function getstatus(url) {
  let index = websites.indexOf(url);
  let result = statuses[index]
  return result
}
```

Or, If you don't want a promise-based approach, you could remove the asynchronous function calls:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const websites = [/* Array of website URL's go here */];
var statuses = [];
for (let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
  var response = axios.get(websites[i]);
  var status = response.status;
  statuses.push(status)
}
function getstatus(url) {
  let index = websites.indexOf(url);
  let result = statuses[index]
  return result
}
```

Though be aware: using the non-promised based approach may occasionally not work, because you are not waiting for a promise change from the `axios.get` function

Feel free to let me know if something doesn't work and I will be glad to check!